# Excessive data received on idle

Tags: 12.04, networking

My computer sometimes downloads excessive amounts of data while on idle (in the 10MiB area) ,so far my only solution is to restart my computer.at first i thought it was a mistake but it is actually tying up my home network

extra relevant info:
- im using wine to run various games , some involve online content (i.e WoW , SC2 , D3)
- my desktop doubles as a hotspot to 3 devices using hostAPD and relevant dependancies , which were to my knowledge idle or disconnected at the time , but my script was still running

-I'm also using the steam Beta on linux and do have games donwloaded/played through it

can anyone recommend some tools or a solution that will help me find what is causing this?

Comment: what is the that application or file name that is getting downloaded on to your system?

Comment: i am yet to find that , im a bit of a newbie to this "behind the scenes" part of things